# I Cant save or update only some items using a vb.net No error come

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2014-express

i have a very Strange problem and i must solve it very fast
i am using sql server 2014 with vb.net 2010 
i have 2 tables first one for save items second one for the movement of this items for sell or buy 
users use it very Well Before yesterday 
the problem in the purches form all the items when the users insert or update the invoice it is ok for all item but only fiew item when he try to insert it and save the system stop on all pcs

when i start to debug my system to check one of this items which have problem i found this error

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

the code which have error on this items only

```
try
If dtDS.HasChanges = True Then

                dbCmdB.DataAdapter = dtAdp
                dtAdp.Update(dtDt)

            End If
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

and i used

```
dtAdp.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
```

to remove the error and i Succeed but i didn't get  any Response and i must restart my application to end the debug

Comment: You wouldnt know if you had an exception because you are eating them all with that empty Try/Catch.  Get rid of it and try again

Comment: i  am use this try catch on debuging only and i make a preakPoint on the Catch ex As Exception to get the error so no problem with me in this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the reason If You make a very huge database do not use the * in any SQL statement Like Select or Delete or any thing